# Re-encoding a Python module

Tags: python

I have a file `english.py` which was created by reformatting the information [here](http://norvig.com/ngrams/count_2w.txt) so the it is represented as a Python dictionary named `bigrams`.

When I go to import the module using:

```
from english import bigrams
```

I get the following error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 5436: invalid continuation byte

I would like to avoid removing as much information as possible, but with that in mind what can I do to `english.py` so that it can be imported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably chose a non-UTF-8 encoding for the .txt file (and the resulting .py file). A decent text editor can re-encode the file to UTF-8. Or you can prepend a line to the  file specifying the actual encoding:

```
# -*- coding: XXX -*-
```

where `XXX` is replaced by [the encoding's name](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings). My guess is that `cp1252` might work (which is the standard Windows encoding where `é` is represented by `0xe9`).